# Create object instance of a class from its name in string variable

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, runtime, system.reflection

I don't know whether this is possible or not, but I would like to know if it is and, if so, how it works. So here is my question:

I have 2-3 custom model classes of my own. For example, `Customer`,
`Employee` and `Product`. I also have a class name in a string. Based on the class name, I want to create an instance and return it to a **view**. How can I achieve this?

I know that one option is an `if/else` statement, but I would like a better, **dynamic** way.

Comment: What you are looking for is reflection, but as a general rule, if you are using reflection, you might be doing something wrong (there are cases where you need reflection, but it's not common).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Having the class name in string is not enough to be able to create its instance.
As a matter of fact you will need full namespace including class name to create an object.

Assuming you have the following:

```
string className = "MyClass";
string namespaceName = "MyNamespace.MyInternalNamespace";
```

Than you you can create an instance of that class, the object of class `MyNamespace.MyInternalNamespace.MyClass` using either of the following techniques:

```
var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(namespaceName, className);
```

or this:

```
var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(namespaceName + "." + className));
```

Hope this helps, please let me know if not.

Comment: I have class name in a string. so basically I dnt knw the class type. Then how could I create object of particular class. In "MyClass myObj = " I have to give MyClass. bt there can be any class.

Comment: I did exactly what you trying to do. As I have mentioned Besides the class name you need the namespace (as a string). Having them both, you can create instance of the object of that class the way I showed. I'll edit the answer to clarify. Thanks for aksing

Comment: Shouldn't that last code read: "var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(namespaceName + "." + className));" (missing dot?)

Comment: hey plz help me i have same problem but this solution doesn't work for me see [Here please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38596936/i-have-a-helper-that-use-activator-createinstancesitaad-models-table-but-n)

Answer (score 9):

```
    string frmName = "frmCustomer";
    //WorldCarUI. is the namespace of the form
    Type CAType = Type.GetType("WorldCarUI." + frmName );
    var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(CAType);
    Form nextForm2 = (Form)myObj;
    nextForm2.Show();
```

this does works..

Regards Avi

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way is to use Activator. Pass class name to GetType and Create new instance.

`ClassInstance s1 = (ClassInstance)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("App.ClassInstance"));`

```
public class ClassInstance
{
    public string StringData { get; set; }
}
```

Regards,
Nik

Answer (score 0):

Activator class does this job in .net and this technique is very usefull for dependency injection kind of scenarios.

```
string NameSpace = "ProjectName.YourNameSpace";
string ProbeClass = "CLassName";

ObjectHandle ProberHandle = Activator.CreateInstance(NameSpace, ProbeClass) as ObjectHandle;
ClassName Prober = ProberHandle.Unwrap() as ClassName;
```

Ensure that you **unwrap** before type casting otherwise it will give conversion error.