# i have a helper that use Activator.CreateInstance("Sitaad.Models","table") but not found assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model

I Have a Helper function in my app_code folder

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayNameFor(string table, string FieldName)
    {
        string Name = "";
        //Type tt = new FilesList().GetType();
        //var Property = tt.GetProperty(FieldName);        
        Type tt = Type.GetType(table, true);        

        var Property = Activator.CreateInstance(tt.FullName,"FilesList").GetType().GetProperty(FieldName);
        var attr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Property, typeof(TurboDisplayAttribute));

        if (attr.GetType() == typeof(TurboDisplayAttribute))
        {
            Name = ((TurboDisplayAttribute)attr).Name;
        }
        G gg = new G();
        gg.SetDbContext(new ApplicationDbContext());
        Name = gg.T(Name);

        return new MvcHtmlString(Name);
    }
```

but when I use this helper in my view :

```
@Helpers.DisplayNameFor("Sitaad.Models", "Order")
```

it says an error : **Could not load type 'Sitaad.Models' from assembly 'App_Code.xiomuct6, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.**

what do i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `App_Code` from configuration settings. In the `Web.Config` it should look something along these lines:

```
<httpModules>
   <add name="LanguageSettingModule" type="LanguageModule" />
</httpModules>
```

Comment: that project closed now, are you sure this work ? if yes, i do it as a correct answer.

Comment: what can i tell you? if you didn't try you wouldn't know, but it worked for me this way, so ...