# How do I return a casted datatype variable from a function?

Tags: c#, .net, function, generics, types

I am creating a function that casts a generic datatype to a specific datatype based on the string passed in (the string represents the datatype we want to return). The casted datatype is then returned.

```cs
public static T Get<T>(string infoType)
{
// Initialise generic datatype variable
T t = default(T);
switch (infoType)
    {
        case "DataType1":
            DataType1 dt1 = new DataType1();
            t = dt1;
            break;
        case "DataType2":
            DataType2 dt2 = new DataType2();
            t = dt2;
            break;
        case "DataType3":
            DataType3 dt3 = new DataType3();
            t = dt3;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return t;
}
```

I am new to generic datatypes and am aware this isn't how you cast a generic datatype variable to a specific datatype but I'm not sure how I would do this. Also, would the set return datatype conflict with a specific datatype being returned?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a cast through object: `t = (T)(object)dt1`. If `T` is not `DataType1` in that case, the cast will throw an `InvalidCastException`

Comment: `t` will always be the type of `T`, not `DatatypeN`.

Comment: Are the different `DataTypeX` types related? Do they share the same base/interface? If so, then a generic type constraint might help. It's really not clear what you are trying to achieve with this code unfortunately, we need more context.

Comment: There is no point passing the string in. The `T` _is_ the type. `return new T();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create object instance of a class having its name in string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449800/) and [How do I instantiate a class given its string name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247598/) and [Create an instance of a class from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223952/) and [How to create a new object instance from a Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752/) and [C# Instantiate a Class from String name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60106768/)

Comment: what will you do if the method is called with ``Get<DataType1>("DataType2")`? this will at best be a runtime exception with the current approach.